# WP7: 3D Perspective Camera Depth Effect

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, 3d, projection, perspective

Lets say I have a Canvas with one Image centered on the screen. When I move the image away from the center, lets say to the upper right corner, I want it to be skewed as if the Canvas was a perspective 3d-camera with a certain FOV. Can this be done somehow? Im playing around with the Perspective-property in Silverlight for WP7 but I cant get the effect Im after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you're looking for: [How to Set this Kind of Perspective Transform in Matrix3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250744/how-to-set-this-kind-of-perspective-transform-in-matrix3d)